# Stack level too deep with ActiveSupport logger after ~ 475 requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After around 475 requests my application produces a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` exception. This is happening reliable and independent of which Controller and method are called. It also happens on multiple rails versions (4.2+, 5.0+) and in combination with multiple application servers (webrick, unicorn, puma). It only happens in development mode. Not in test and not in staging (which deploys to Tomcat with JRuby). Im using ruby-2.3.1 and jruby-9.1.2.0.

Here is the relevant part of the log:

```
2016-09-20 15:38:14 +0200: Rack app error handling request { GET /kw }
#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/request.rb:361:in `split'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/request.rb:361:in `split_ip_addresses'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/request.rb:349:in `ip'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:226:in `ip'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:53:in `started_request_message'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `block in call_app'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:427:in `add'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/logger.rb:77:in `add'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/logger.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in broadcast'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/logger.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in broadcast'

### above line repeated 483 times ###

/home/mwinter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:490:in `info'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/request_store-1.3.1/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@demo_foo_bar/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'


Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm searching for direct solutions to the issue or ideas how to debug/find the cause of the error.

Comment: Please try to use `2.2` ruby branch. I believe this could happen because of `Logger#debug` implementation (since you do not experience the problem in both test/staging.)

Comment: @mudasobwa I got it working on ruby-2.2.5 but to no avail, still getting the same error https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1aa3ed3a58285ba9040b099ba93e1956

Comment: Sorry for putting you into this redundant fight against 2.2. Please share the 16th line of `/home/mwinter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@demo_foo_bar/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/logger.rb` file (±5 lines above and below.) I bet it’s inside `debug` method definition, right?

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks for helping. I posted the [logger.rb](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/411d0bd0e5d4cc4ca9379de344699420#file-gistfile1-txt-L16) line 16 is dynamic add method.

Comment: It sounds like in `development` env you have a circular references of loggers. Unfortunately, I have no idea how this could happen, but I would go with monkeypatching this `ActiveSupport::Logger`, by copy-paste from the original code the whole method _save for the call to `super`_. I know this is not the most elegant solution, and you still have an option to dig into your loggers structure, but the latter would definitely do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I monkeypatched away the super in `add` and `close` and I don't run into the `SystemStackError` anymore. I'm going to search for the circular dependency now. First step: selectively deactivate gems.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the rails-footnotes gem v 4.1.8 completely to solve the issue.

Issue reported as [#156](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes/issues/156).